# #1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST inside of a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

First time posting here.
I'm trying to do a full text search within a stored procedure and for some reason one of my tables is causing the error "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST". Here is the code for the procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getHits(
  IN qry VARCHAR (100),
  IN shft VARCHAR(10),
  IN offc INT,
  OUT proj INT,
  OUT notes INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)
    INTO notes
  FROM Shift
  WHERE Shift_ID = shft 
    AND O_ID= offc 
    AND MATCH(Notes) AGAINST(qry IN BOOLEAN MODE);

  SELECT count(*)
    INTO proj
  FROM Pers_On_Shift
  WHERE Shift_ID = shft 
    AND Office_ID= offc 
    AND MATCH(Project) AGAINST(qry IN BOOLEAN MODE);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The first "select" statement is executed without a problem however the second one throws the error "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST". Where I am confused is, why it accepts qry in the first case but not in the second case.

I have run these queries outside of the procedure and both work without issue. I have fulltext indices on column being searched. I have also tried running it inside of a prepared statement:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getHits(
  IN qry TEXT,
  IN shft VARCHAR(10),
  IN offc INT,
  OUT proj INT)
BEGIN
  SET @shft=shft;
  SET @offc=offc;
  SET @match_query=qry;

  SET @Dyna_SQL="SELECT count(*)
                 FROM Shift
                 WHERE Shift_ID = ?
                  AND O_ID= ? 
                  AND MATCH(Notes) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE);";

PREPARE stmt FROM @Dyna_SQL;
EXECUTE stmt USING @shft,@offc,@match_query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

but that keeps failing as well.

Any help would be appreciated as I have wasted more time trying to figure this out than I would care to admit.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: why are u using @ in your procedure?

Comment: I'm using the @ as a means of getting the parameter values passed into the prepared statement.

Comment: I do that and a new error comes up saying it "Can't find the FULLTEXT index matching the column list". I have reset the index on that column and it still comes up with the error

Comment: I ran EXPLAIN and it still only gives me the same error. Is this still a potential issue if the only index on that table is on the "Notes" column.

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) from Shift WHERE Shift_ID='20150304_n' AND O_ID=3 AND MATCH(Notes) AGAINST('Ninjo' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
ERROR 1191 (HY000): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: something weird is going on; the fulltext index is not showing up when I run that from command line but it comes up when I look at the table structure in phpmyadmin. I can run a FULLTEXT query from PHPmyAdmin but not from the command line. I am running MySQL 5.6.21 and the starge engine is InnoDB.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Shift ADD FULLTEXT(Notes). works in phpmyadmin but not command line.

Comment: I've removed the index from phpmyadmin. When I run your command it gives me a syntax error near USING BTREE part. If I leave it out, I get "ERROR 1283 (HY000): Column 'Notes' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index
"

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want but it's a TEXT column with latin1_swedish_ci collation, NOT NULL and no default value set.

Comment: easier said than done since I have a lot of foreign key constraints on this table

Comment: ok that got the index added at the command line. But I'm still getting the same error stating  "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST" when I try to run the first procedure that I listed above.

Comment: try removing the `IN BOOLEAN  MODE` from query... You query string is not using boolean mode search... the correct way to use that would be for example `AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Comment: the example query that I'm using here is just a simple one to demonstrate how I am calling the procedure. In production the boolean mode is a requirement.

Comment: Yes but in boolean mode is expecting arguments like I showed above...When you are testing are you passing arguments as described above?